# How to round up to next 10 if a number is greater than 1 and round down if a number is less than 1 but more than 0?

Tags: java, math, rounding

For example round up 341 to 350 but round down 340.8 to 340.I have tried the code below but it doesn't do what i desire.

```
public static double roundToNearestTen(double 
number) {
        if (number >= 1) {
            double roundedUp =     Math.ceil(number / 10) * 10;
            double roundedDown = Math.floor(number / 10) * 10;
            return (number - roundedDown) < (roundedUp - number) ? roundedDown : roundedUp;
        } else {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So your result will always be an integer that is a multiple of 10 ?

Comment: Improve the question. Show example inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs. Your code has `if (number >= 1)`, which treats all values of `number` that are greater or equal to 1 equally. But, your example indicates you want to treat `341.0` differently than `340.8`. As a result, it isn't clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to do this ? That is, round down to the nearest 10 if a number is an integer or has a unit digit less than 1, and round up to the nearest 10 if the unit digit is more than or equal to 1 ?

```
public static double roundToNearestTen(double 
 number) {
    if (number % 10 >= 1) {
        return Math.ceil(number / 10) * 10;
    } else {
        return Math.floor(number / 10) * 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yesss exactly this. I have been trying this for days but without any result. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi. What's a "decimal part"?

Comment: @Stef, I believe they are referring to the fractional portion of the value.

Comment: @Reilas I don't think so, no. The fractional part is never higher than 1.

Comment: You guys are right I was not very clear sorry. I have edited with the last unit digit is less than 1, it's still not perfectly clear so feel free to propose an edit if you find a better way to express this :)

Comment: @Stef, isn't that called, the "decimal"?